# Deleted easy-rsa folders, what to do

Tags: server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I've been following a [tutorial](https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/tutorial-installing-openvpn-on-ubuntu-16-04/) to setup an OpenVPN server. However, it didn't work and I decided to remove OpenVPN and try again. I did it with

```
sudo apt-get purge openvpn
```

command and then

```
rm -rf /etc/openvpn/
rm -rf /usr/share/easy-rsa/
rm - rf /usr/share/doc/easy-rsa/
rm -rf /root/openvpn-ca/
rm -rf /root/openvpn-clients/
rm -rf /run/openvpn/
```

Now having run

```
 sudo apt-get install openvpn easy-rsa

 make-cadir ~/openvpn-ca
```

I get a note:

```
 cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/easy-rsa/vars': No such file or directory
 cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/easy-rsa/*.cnf': No such file or directory
```

When I then  cd to ~/openvpn-ca and ls I don't get any files, while. according to tutorial, there should be file vars there.

What should I do now? I'd think the reinstallation would create all the files necessary, but it seems that vars file hasn't been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely *reinstallation* will fix it - but that's not what you did

Having manually deleted files belonging to the `easy-rsa` package, the package manager has no idea they're gone. So when you did

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn easy-rsa
```

you likely got a message that `easy-rsa is already the newest version` and no files were actually restored: try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall easy-rsa
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to have fixed it!